# removing empty header columns from a data matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have got a matrix with the header which looks like this:

```
"ID" "age" "sex" "status" "" "fup"

 1 32 f 1 5 20

 2 45 m 0 6 35

 3 21 f 1 8 5
```

How can I remove the columns with missing header values? (i.e. columns for which the header reads `""`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `nzchar` on the column names of the matrix to return a logical index of `TRUE/FALSE` values for non-blank/blank names.  Then, based on that index, subset the columns.

```
 m1[,nzchar(colnames(m1))]
```

If the dataset have mixed class, it is better to store it in a `list` or `data.frame`.

Comment: nice function (`nzchar`)

Comment: just saw `matrix()` function has `dimnames` as one of its arguments. Kool. Tried creating matrix with dimension names and applied `nzchar()`. Thank you.

Comment: Why would that be, because `names(df)` and `colnames(df)` generates same output, isn't it?

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian  Not in `matrix`.  You can check `m1 <- matrix(1:10, ncol=2, dimnames =list(NULL, c("col1", "col2")));  m1[, colnames(m1)=='col1', drop = FALSE]` and with `names`

Comment: Yes `names()` does not work with matrix, but it does work with data frame. `colnames()` and `rownames()` works for matrices.

Comment: I observed one more thing, when I convert a `matrix` with a colname `""` to a `dataframe`, it is substituted by R's header i.e. `V1` or `V2`, then that way even after converting `matrix to dataframe`, we won't be able to remove colnames `""` if there were any at first place in a matrix
`m1 <- matrix(1:10, ncol=2, dimnames =list(NULL, c("col1", "")));m1 <- as.data.frame(m1);m1;m1[!colnames(m1)==""]`

Why people are upvoting, I should delete it. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian  In `data.frame`, you need a column name.  But, you can assign column name to `'''`. i.e. `names(m1)[2] <- ""` (after converting to data.frame.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114109/discussion-between-sowmya-s-manian-and-akrun).

Answer (score 2):

One of the solution is achieved by converting `matrix` to `dataframe`

```
 mat <- matrix(1:10, ncol=2, dimnames =list(1:5, c("col1", "")))
 mat
 mat1 <- as.data.frame(mat)
 mat1 
 names(mat1)[2] <- ""
 result <- mat1[!names(mat1)==""]
 result
```

Comment: `names` doesn't work on matrices. I was going to post something like `m1[,colnames(m1)>0]`, but it's essentially the same as `nzchar` from @akrun solution

Answer (score 1):

As you don't have data of the same type (all columns are numeric apart from "sex" which is character) it is better to use a data frame.

You can convert your matrix to a data frame with `as.data.frame()`. This will replace all empty column names with V followed by the column index (e.g. in your example the empty string will be replaced by "V5").

You can use `grepl()` to filter out columns starting with "V" but I suggest using the select function from the `dplyr` package as it results in more readable code:

`as.data.frame(your_example_matrix) %>% select(-matches("^V"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use grepl function for removing column names with " "

```
mat <- matrix(1:20, ncol=4, dimnames =list(1:5, c("col1", "col2", "col3", "")))

mat1 <- data.frame(mat)

names(mat1)[4] <- ""

mat1[,grepl("[A-z]",colnames(mat1))]

  col1 col2 col3
1    1    6   11
2    2    7   12
3    3    8   13
4    4    9   14
5    5   10   15
```

#data copied from @sowmya

Answer (score 0):

The above answers didn't work for me. Let's say you have a dataframe with some empty headers, and you want to delete the columns with the empty headers.

where df is your dataframe:

```r
df <- df[!is.na(names(df))]
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like any columns are `NA`—the data format in the question isn't totally clear but I don't think that's even possible. It's a blank string.